# Wordpress - display posts that I commented

Tags: wordpress

I have in my website a custom page, that display latest posts, popular posts, and I want display now latest posts that I commented on. One of my query look like:

```
<?php       
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;       
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order'=> 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();

    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) ); 
?>
```

I use pagenavi plugin to display pagination of that loop.

Do you have any idea how to create a custom loop to do that? I did many search to see if possible to display posts that I commented in wordpress, but no look.

I don't know if possible in stackoverflow, but I can pay extra if needed for who want help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amine.

Try this.

```
<?php       
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;       
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order'=> 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
    } 
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) ); 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```